# Matrix Singularity Constraint

Tags: constraint, cvxpy

I'm using CVXPY. Given a $2\times2$ matrix $A$, is it possible to add a singularity constraint?

Anything equivalent to:

- $|A| = 0$: The determinant is $0$
- $\operatorname{rank}(A) \leq 1$
- Smallest eigenvalue is $0$
- etc...

Comment: [X-posted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66815171/6338725). I would expect someone with some 15K rep points on SO to know the etiquette.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Yes, I'm aware - it's just that this site is a better fit but still in Beta so I wasn't sure about the right place to put it... I should have at least put a cross-link. Sorry.

Comment: Try to use the nuclear norm instead of the rank. It is convex, at least.

Comment: With proper scaling this does seem to do the trick when I put it in the *objective* and minimize it. It does not let me create a constraint with it though.

Comment: My objective looks smt like this: `cp.Maximize(cp.log_det(m1) + cp.log_det(m2) - cp.normNuc(x))`. IIUC, `normNuc()` is the sum of $e_i$. So when I minimize it, it indeed tends to push $e_0$ to $0$, but then it also proceeds to scale down $e_1$ which then in turn penalizes the first two terms `cp.log_det(m1) + cp.log_det(m2)`.

Comment: I don't have the big picture. If you edited your question and showed all your work and made an effort to present it clearly, it would be easier for everyone.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: OK. It's part of a bigger probelem so I may post it as a different question altogether then. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6):

No, it is an intrinsically non-convex constraint. Just take a diagonal matrix, and the feasible set would be the coordinate axes, i.e. nonconvex and highly ill-conditioned as the feasible set has measure 0.

Comment: I have an upper bound and a lower for all the matrix values. Does that help?

Comment: No, you're still looking at the coordinate axes in the special case, but now constrained to a box. In general for a 2x2 matrix you have a quadratic equality $a_1 a_4-a_2 a_3 = 0$

Comment: Yes. Ofc. But that’s non affine and CVXPY won’t let me add that expression. It’s non DCP.

Comment: Yes, that is precisely what this answer says. It is a non-convex constraint.